# Copy folder if it exists locally

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a list of domains, and I want Ansible to check if a folder with the same name exists locally, then copy it over to the target server and skip if the folder doesn't exist locally.

I'm not sure on how to use `when` in `copy custom files` task.

I have this so far:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    domains:
    - domain: domain1.com
    - domain: domain2.com
    - domain: domain3.com
  tasks:
  - name: check for website files
    local_action: stat path={{ playbook_dir }}/files/var/www/{{ item.domain }}
    register: files_check
    with_items: "{{ domains }}"

  - name: print variable facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ files_check }}"

  - name: copy custom files
    copy:
      src: files/var/www/{{ item.domain }}
      dest: /var/www/{{ item.domain }}
      owner: root
      group: root
      force: true
    with_items: "{{ domains }}"
    when: ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Testing the paths on the controller](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths) is simple. You don't need the *stat* module. When the variable *src* keeps the path use the condition below

```yaml
    when: src is exists
```

For example, given the tree

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── files
│   └── var
│       └── www
│           ├── domain1.com
│           └── domain2.com
├── hosts
└── pb.yml
```

, the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
test_11
test_13
```

, and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    domains:
      - domain1.com
      - domain2.com
      - domain3.com

  tasks:

  - name: copy custom files
    copy:
      src: "{{ src }}"
      dest: "/var/www/{{ item }}"
      owner: root
      group: root
      force: true
    loop: "{{ domains }}"
    when: src is exists
    vars:
      src: "files/var/www/{{ item }}"
```

give, running in *--check --diff* mode

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -CD

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [copy custom files] *********************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => (item=domain1.com)
ok: [test_13] => (item=domain1.com)
ok: [test_11] => (item=domain2.com)
skipping: [test_11] => (item=domain3.com) 
ok: [test_13] => (item=domain2.com)
skipping: [test_13] => (item=domain3.com) 

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Notes:

- You don't need *playbook_dir*. You can use relative paths. See [Search paths in Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#search-paths-in-ansible) and the subsection [The magic of ‘local’ paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#the-magic-of-local-paths) in particular.

Comment: This is working perfectly.
If you want to use this with a role based setup, then I was only able to make it work with absolute path (role_path) like this:

`src: "{{ role_path }}/files/var/www/{{ item.domain }}"`